# Proper explanation of JavaScript execution order

Tags: javascript

I know there are lots of question on this subject, but all of them are tailored to a specific case. I'm asking this question and hoping for an answer that everyone can use when looking into this matter.

Say I have three functions that need to be executed in order, and they all do something async.

For two functions it's simple with a callback:

```
var fOne = function(callback) {
  // do stuff
  callback();
};

var fTwo = function() {
  // do stuff
};
```

Calling:

```
fOne(fTwo);
```

Makes fTwo to be run after fOne is complete. How does one add fThree into this case so that it is run after fTwo, which is run after fOne?

Comment: depends when you want fThree to execute

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: edited my question accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Basically, if I understand your question right, you'll want to pass a lambda to fOne in order to be able to add arguments to fTwo, then have fTwo collect the callback and call it like fOne does.

```
var fOne = function(callback) {
  // do stuff
  callback();
};

var fTwo = function(callback) {
  // do stuff
  callback();
};

var fThree = function() {
  // do stuff
};

fOne(function() { fTwo(fThree); }); // <- lambda
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not using deferred and promises to run simultaneous asyncronous actions, but rather just starting one when the other has completed, adding a third goes pretty much the same way:

```
var fOne = function(callback) {
   console.log('1')
   callback();
};

var fTwo = function(callback) {
   console.log('2')
   callback();
};

var fThree = function() {
   console.log('3')
};

fOne(function() {
    fTwo(function() {
        fThree();
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gc9dr/)

Comment: This is still not giving the right result for me, would using deferreds be a better option?

Comment: It executes the functions in perfect order, what result are you expecting ?

Comment: I think I haven't given enough information. fOne and fTwo both fill an iframe with content. They need to be doing that one after another due to login issues. Therefore fTwo is in the callback of fOne. In fTwo all my code is in a .load block where a button is pressed that leads to a second page. fThree can't be called until the new load is done, I'm starting to think my problem is in there.

Comment: @Difusio - That's something completely different, and what you need to do is bind handlers to the onload events of the iframe when you change the source or whatever it is you do. Just stacking functions wont do the trick.

Comment: @Difusio if you are talking about the jQuery `load` function, place your callback within the callback of the `load` call, e.g. `$("#stuff").load(url+" "+elementID, function() { fThree(); })`

Answer (score 1):

One more approach I came up with:

```
var stack = [fOne, fTwo, fThree];
stack.shift()(function() {
    stack.shift()(stack[0]);
});
```

Where you define your functins as:

```
function fOne(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() { // <-- example of async task
        alert('fOne done');
        callback && callback();
    }, 1000);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kRMr8/2/